# Which groups does the user jenkins belong to?

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to configure a post-build action, but it fails on a file copy/touch command.

In the log output of jenkins the situation is clear, jenkins is not a member of the group tomcat7, so he doesn't have the right to create that file.

Jenkins-Console-Log:

```
[...]
SNAPSHOT/web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
channel stopped
[workspace] $ /bin/bash -xe /tmp/hudson7730141733158377543.sh
+ whoami
jenkins
+ ls -lat /var/lib/tomcat7/webappsTnbt/
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 3 tomcat7 tomcat7 4096 Sep 12 00:38 .
drwxrwxr-x 2 tomcat7 tomcat7 4096 Sep 12 00:15 web-1.0-SNAPSHOT
drwxr-xr-x 8 root    root    4096 Sep 12 00:14 ..
+ groups
jenkins
+ touch /var/lib/tomcat7/webappsTnbt/foo.txt
touch: cannot touch `/var/lib/tomcat7/webappsTnbt/foo.txt': Permission denied
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

What I don't understand is, on the operating system level, the user jenkins is member of the group tomcat7.

I added that user to the /etc/group file and when I login in using ssh I get the following responses on the command line:

```
$ whoami
jenkins
$ groups
jenkins tomcat7
```

and esp. the touch command works.

So why does the group membership differ for the jenkins user for those two situations described above?

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you restart jenkins after you added the jenkins user to tomcat7 group ?

Comment: Strange, either restarting the machine or restarting jenkins did do the trick. Since I did both I'm not able to tell wich one did the trick. I seriously didn't expect that. @nos if you rephrase your comment as an answer I will check that.